# WordPress Function on first Theme Activation

Tags: wordpress

is there a way to execute a function only on the first activation of a specific theme?

I found this code but the problem is that the function will execute after every theme switch

```
<?php add_action("after_switch_theme", "mytheme_do_something"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by writing and checking an option.

```
add_action("after_switch_theme", "mytheme_do_something");
function mytheme_do_something() {
     if( ! get_option( 'mytheme_setting' ) ) {
         add_option( 'mytheme_setting', '1');
         // some things you want to do
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that would be more complicated :)